# Yii2: не выводятся теги iframe, object в виджетах DetailView и GridView

Tags: yii2, yii

Здравствуйте. Не выводятся теги iframe, object в виджетах DetailView и GridView. Имею следующий код:

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'title',
            [
                'attribute'=>'src',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    return "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='{$data->src}'  frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
                },
                'format'=>'html',
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
```

и

```
DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'title',
            [
                'attribute'=>'src',
                'value'=>"<iframe width='560' height='315' src='{$model->src}' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                'format'=>'html',
            ],
        ],
    ])
```

Указанный html не выводится, в <td></td> пусто, любой другой тег выводится без проблем. Как это решить? Спасибо.

Comment: если не изменяет память, format должен быть raw

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было использовать формат raw вместо html: 'format'=>'raw'

Comment: Окей, уговорили! Впредь буду писать ответами.